# ConsumerWidget with streamProvider is built infinitely

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

ConsumerWidget with streamProvider is built infinitely.　getCommunityByName methods of repository and controller are not executing infinitely, only the build method of screen is executing infinitely. print function of the build method confirms it.What do you think is the cause? Below is the code.

screen

```
class CommunityScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  final String name;
  const CommunityScreen({super.key, required this.name});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final community = ref.watch(getCommunityByNameProvider(name));
    print("community: $community");
    print("--------------------");
    return Scaffold(
      body: community.when(
          data: (community) => Container(),
          error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(error: error.toString()),
          loading: () => const Loader()),
    );
  }
}
```

controller

```
final communityControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CommunityController, bool>((ref) {
  final communityRepository = ref.watch(communityRepositoryProvider);
  return CommunityController(
    communityRepository: communityRepository,
    ref: ref,
  );
});

final getCommunityByNameProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, String name) {
  return ref
      .watch(communityControllerProvider.notifier)
      .getCommunityByName(name);
});

class CommunityController extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  final CommunityRepository _communityRepository;
  final Ref _ref;
  CommunityController({
    required CommunityRepository communityRepository,
    required Ref ref,
  })  : _communityRepository = communityRepository,
        _ref = ref,
        super(false);

  void createCommunity(String name, BuildContext context) async {
    state = true;
    final uid = _ref.read(userProvider)?.uid ?? '';
    Community community = Community(
      id: name,
      name: name,
      banner: Constants.bannerDefault,
      avatar: Constants.avatarDefault,
      members: [uid],
      mods: [uid],
    );

    final res = await _communityRepository.createCommunity(community);
    state = false;
    res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
      showSnackBar(context, 'Community created successfully!');
      Routemaster.of(context).pop();
    });
  }

  Future<Community> getCommunityByName(String name) {
    return _communityRepository.getCommunityByName(name);
  }
}
```

repository

```
final communityRepositoryProvider = Provider((ref) {
  return CommunityRepository(firestore: ref.watch(firestoreProvider));
});

class CommunityRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore;
  CommunityRepository({required FirebaseFirestore firestore})
      : _firestore = firestore;

  Stream<Community> getCommunityByName(String name) {
    return _communities.doc(name).snapshots().map(
        (event) => Community.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }

  FutureVoid createCommunity(Community community) async {
    try {
      var communityDoc = await _communities.doc(community.name).get();
      if (communityDoc.exists) {
        throw 'Community with the same name already exists!';
      }

      return right(_communities.doc(community.name).set(community.toMap()));
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      throw e.message!;
    } catch (e) {
      return left(Failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  CollectionReference get _communities =>
      _firestore.collection(FirebaseConstants.communitiesCollection);
}
```

Comment: First, stop using StateNotifier[Provider].  You should move to Notifier or AsyncNotifier, because then you'd see the second problem.  You're asking a provider to return a stream, and it's not a Stream[Notifier]Provider, so it keeps recreating the stream.  If you want to cache a stream instance, use a StreamProvider.

Comment: I appreciate your response.The code in your question was incorrect, I used StateNotifier because it is needed by other functions in the Controller. The code in question has been corrected. What exactly do I need to fix?

Comment: You're still using a StateNotifier.  I'll wait, I guess.